# No certificate matches private key while generating .p12 file

Tags: ssl, pkcs#12

I have successfully generated `.p12` file but I got a message which is a follows:

```
C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin>openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey mykey.key -in exported.pem -out myfile.p12
```

Loading 'screen' into random state - done
**No certificate matches private key**

Could anyone tell me what is this error all about?

Also, the size of the file `myfile.p12` is 0KB and when I tried to open it, I got the following message in a small window with OK button:

`Invalid Public Key Security Object File

This file is invalid for use as the following: Personal Information Exchange `

Please clarify.

Thanks

Comment: Do I need to chose to export to BASE64 to get it to work as per the following document?http://www.markbrilman.nl/2012/07/openssl-error-no-certificate-matches-private-key-when-creating-pfx/

Comment: Well, I did export to BASE64 but still getting the same error. Still wondering what could be the problem. The only difference is that the certificate is exported in PEM format.
Source: http://www.markbrilman.nl/2012/07/openssl-error-no-certificate-matches-private-key-when-creating-pfx/

Answer (score 26):

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40017778/372055)

OpenSSL says *no certificate matches private key* when the certificate is DER-encoded. Just change it to PEM encoding before creating the PKCS#12.

1. *Create key pair* : 
   `openssl genrsa -out aps_development.key 2048`
2. *Create CSR* : `openssl req -new -sha256 -key aps_development.key -out aps_development.csr`
3. Upload the CSR to developer portal to get the certificate `aps_development.cer`
4. *Convert the certificate*: `openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in aps_development.cer -out aps_development.pem`
5. *Build the PKCS#12*: `openssl pkcs12 -inkey aps_development.key -in aps_development.pem -export -out aps_development.p12`

Comment: This works, but as soon as I add intermediate and root with more "-in" arguments it fails with "no certificate matches private key". But I need those as well. There has to be another reason for this.

Comment: I found my problem: The certificates were not in the correct order. Somehow this matters and gives you the misleading message _no certificate matches private key_.

Comment: found another solution:  
_cat domain.crt intermediate.crt ca.crt > bundle.crt_  
_openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey key -in bundle.crt_

Comment: Perfect, tahnksss

Comment: Correct order/command in my case was as follows:
Openssl pkcs12 -export -out alwayson.pfx -inkey C:\ssl\private.key -in C:\ssl\ca_bundle.crt -in C:\ssl\certificate.crt
So, intermediates and bundles before the certificate it seems.

Comment: Same as Mikael Dyreborg Hansen : I needed to put intermediate CA before the certificate

Comment: Man, this makes the whole process totally simple. Does not even need a MAC to do that! awesome answer. If I could I would reward you with 500 reps.

Answer (score 19):

I also had exactly same issue. Below two commands worked like a charm.

```
cat domain.crt intermediate.crt ca.crt > bundle.crt 

openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.pfx -inkey key -in bundle.crt
```

Comment: +1 This is the solution that worked for me, the ones above did not. I presume it has something to do with the files being extracted from a zip file on Windows, but then running openssl from WSL (Ubuntu).

Comment: what if you dont have an intermediate certificate? will it work?

Comment: this solution worked for me after downloading crt's and key from zerossl

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I'd actually specified the wrong certificate -- i.e. the certificate was for one system, and the private key for another. So the error message was spot-on!

Answer (score 0):

Use these commands to compare the RSA Public-Key component of your CSR to that of the private key.

Key: openssl pkey -text_pub -in file.key -noout

CSR: openssl req -in file.csr -noout -text

These must match for 'openssl pkcs12' to create the export file.

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was solved by changing the **access permissions** and the special mode flags of the files (`chmod 644` worked - before I didn't have '**read**' permissions for the *Group* and *Other* classes)