# Convert p7b file into p12 file format

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, certificate, rsa

I have generated `pem` and `csr` files using the below command.

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out req.csr`

After this, I sent `csr` file to the authority and got `p7b` certificate.

Now, I tried to convert `p7b` file to `p12` format with the below commands.

```
openssl pkcs7 -print_certs -in certificate.p7b -out certificate.cer
openssl pkcs12 -export -out certificate.p12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.cer
```

However, it gives the below error.

```
No certificate matches private key
error in pkcs12
```

How can I convert `p7b` file into `p12` file format?

Comment: Do any of these help: [add -nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24477766/11609403), [convert DER to PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43817683/11609403), [cat the CA bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64662371/11609403), [validate key and cert](https://serverfault.com/a/955451)?

Answer (score -1):

I think you must call privatekey file

openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey privateKey.key -out certificate.p12 -inkey key.pem -in certificate.cer

Comment: Please write your answers in a way that is clear and understandable.
For code use the ```  ``` mark or the 4 indentations, to style the code and seperate it from the regular text.